# I'm trying to adjust minecraft to run smoothly on my acer aspire, but now I've got the video settings all messed up.

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to adjust minecraft to run smoothly on my acer aspire, but now I've got the video settings all messed up. I want to uninstall minecraft and start from scratch, but it's not on my list of programs to uninstall. How do I start from scratch?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Reinstall-Minecraft backup your save data before doing that.

Comment: Isn't there a reset to default setting?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to uninstall minecraft to reset your video settings. Here's how to do it.

On Windows:

1. From the **Start Menu**, select **Run...** (or press Windows key+R)
2. Enter **%APPDATA%\.minecraft** and press **OK**
3. Locate the file **options.txt** and delete it. If you have optifine installed, delete **ofoptions.txt** too.
4. Start your minecraft app. All settings will be back to the default.

On a Mac:

1. Go to your Finder
2. From the **Go** menu up at the top, click **Go to Folder...** (Shift+Command+G)
3. Enter the following and click **OK**: ~/Library/Application
   Support/minecraft
4. Delete **options.txt** and **ofoptions.txt** (if you have optifine)
5. Start your minecraft app. All settings will be back to the default.

Note: On a Mac, you have to do exactly as I say in step 3 because the folder is hidden. You can't browse to it from the finder unless you have hidden files turned off.

Comment: Hi Tyler. Welcome to Arqade. This is a really good answer and contribution to the site, a fantastic first answer!

Comment: On Mac Os X 10.6.8 or lower the Library folder is visible by default. To show it in Mac Os X 10.7 or higher, open Terminal and type `chflags nohidden ~/Library/`. If you want to hide it again simply change the `nohidden` to `hidden`.

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft is located in your appdata folder in a .minecraft folder,

On windows it's as easy as going to `%APPDATA%\.minecraft` and deleting what you need from there. You won't need to delete the saves folder if you want to keep your worlds