# I can't get rid of the Super Secret Settings, even after restarting

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, ubuntu

I've already read some of the similar topics here but none of the suggestions work. No F4, no fn+F4, no restarting the game. Actually, even after months, Minecraft still looks like Super Secret Settings is enabled no matter which world I play in.

I have no idea if it is relevant but I'm using Ubuntu. The problem occurred with several versions of the game already (since its been months).

Comment: Try resetting your video settings by deleting $HOME/.minecraft/options.txt. Same instructions for PC/Mac here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189732/im-trying-to-adjust-minecraft-to-run-smoothly-on-my-acer-aspire-but-now-ive-g/189788#189788

Comment: To anyone else who might vote to close as "unclear what you're asking": [**the Super Secret Settings actually do stuff**](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Secret_Settings)

Comment: It might be a silly question, but have you tried the 3rd answer on [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139370/how-do-i-turn-off-the-minecraft-1-7-2-super-secret-settings) regarding repeatedly cycling through until the F3 menu shows there's no shader?  That seems to be missing from the things you listed you tried.

Comment: I tried cycling through them, too. That used to work but not anymore.

Comment: About Tyler's suggestion; where do I find that txt? I can't seem to. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: You need to go to $HOME/.minecraft to find the txt file. The same location where minecraft is installed. It is a hidden file, so if you're browsing with the File Browser on Ubuntu, press Ctrl+H to show hidden files.